# How to use Struts 2 with JFreeChart?

Tags: struts2, jfreechart

Firstly, I went here ( http://code.google.com/p/struts2-examples/downloads/list and I downloaded Hello_World_Struts2_Mvn.zip) and I run that example.

After that, I went here (http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/jfreechart-plugin.html), I add the dependencies for  **commons-lang-2.5.jar**, **jcommon-1.0.16.jar** and **jfreechart-1.0.13.jar** and I modify the example downloaded from code.google.com to see how **JFreeChart** is working, but I receive this error:

```
Unable to load configuration. - action - file:/C:/.../untitled_war_exploded/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:34:67

Caused by: Error building results for action createChart in namespace  - action - file:/C:/.../out/artifacts/untitled_war_exploded/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:34:67

Caused by: There is no result type defined for type 'chart' mapped with name 'success'.  Did you mean 'chart'? - result - file:/C:/.../out/artifacts/untitled_war_exploded/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:36:49
```

At the line 36 in struts.xml is the this code (the code from struts2 website):

```
<action name="viewModerationChart" class="myapp.actions.ViewModerationChartAction">
  <result name="success" type="chart">
    <param name="width">400</param>
    <param name="height">300</param> 
  </result>
</action>
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define Action mappings related to chart differently in Struts.xml.Change your project's struts.xml with Jfreechart related actions and define it in separate package.
For eg.

```
<package name="struts2" extends="jfreechart-default">  
<action name="viewModerationChart" class="myapp.actions.ViewModerationChartAction">
  <result name="success" type="chart">
    <param name="width">400</param>
    <param name="height">300</param> 
  </result>
</action>
</package>
```

Comment: Is there any way to generate jfreechart in struts2 without using struts-jfreechart plugin